# TDD Django tests seem to skip certain parts of the view code

Tags: django, tdd

I'm writing some tests for a site using django TDD.

The problem is that when I manually go to the testserver. Fill in the form and submit it then it seems to works fine. But when I run the test using manage.py test wiki it seems to skip parts of the code within the view. The page parts all seem to work fine. But the pagemod-parts within the code and even a write() I created just to see what was going on seems to be ignored.

I have no idea what could be causing this and can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas?

This is the code:

test.py

```
#imports
class WikiSiteTest(LiveServerTestCase):
....
def test_wiki_links(self):
    '''Go to the site, and check a few links'''
    #creating a few objects which will be used later
    .....
    #some code to get to where I want:
    .....

    #testing the link to see if the tester can add pages
    link = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Add page (for testing only. delete this later)')
    link.click()

    #filling in the form
    template_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('template')
    template_field.send_keys('homepage')
    slug_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('slug')
    slug_field.send_keys('this-is-a-slug')
    title_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('title')
    title_field.send_keys('this is a title')
    meta_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('meta_description')
    meta_field.send_keys('this is a meta')
    content_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('content')
    content_field.send_keys('this is content')

    #submitting the filled form so that it can be processed
    s_button = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Submit']")
    s_button.click() 
    # now the view is called
```

and a view:

views.py

```
def page_add(request):
'''This function does one of these 3 things:
    - Prepares an empty form
    - Checks the formdata it got. If its ok then it will save it and create and save
      a copy in the form of a Pagemodification.
    - Checks the formdata it got. If its not ok then it will redirect the user back'''
.....

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = request.user.get_profile()
        page = form.save(commit=False)
        page.partner = user.partner
        page.save() #works

        #Gets ignored
        pagemod = PageModification() 
        pagemod.template = page.template
        pagemod.parent = page.parent 
        pagemod.page = Page.objects.get(slug=page.slug)
        pagemod.title = page.title
        pagemod.meta_description = page.meta_description
        pagemod.content = page.content
        pagemod.author = request.user.get_profile()
        pagemod.save()
        f = open("/location/log.txt", "w", True)
        f.write('are you reaching this line?')
        f.close()
        #/gets ignored

        #a render to response
```

Then later I do:

test.py

```
print '###############Data check##################'
print Page.objects.all()
print PageModification.objects.all()
print '###############End data check##############'
```

And get:

terminal:

```
###############Data check##################
[<Page: this is a title 2012-10-01 14:39:21.739966+00:00>]
[]
###############End data check##############
```

All the imports are fine. Putting the page.save() after the ignored code makes no difference.
This only happens when running it through the TDD test.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this was a long time ago.

It was solved but the solution was a little embarrassing. Basically, it was me being stupid. I can't remember the exact details but I believe a different view was called instead of the one that I showed here. That view had the same code except the "skipped" part.

My apologies to anyone who took their time looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

How very strange.  Could it be that the view is somehow erroring at the `Pagemodification` stage?  Have you got any checks later on in your test that assert that the response from the view is coming through correctly, ie that a 500 error is not being returned instead?